# Cambiar idioma datetimepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

me gustaría poder cambiar el idioma del datetimepicker y no hay forma de hacerlo, he visto algunos ejemplos y no me cambia nada.

```js
function datepicker(){ 
  $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "d-m-Y",
    language: 'es',
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text"
         id="idFechaAltaConv"
         class="form-control input-sm datepicker " />
</div>
```

Comment: edito tu pregunta para poder ejecutar tu código, aún así  tu ejemplo no está completo y faltan llamadas por ejemplo a la función datepicker.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambiar idioma en datetimepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258110/cambiar-idioma-en-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema reside en la documentación que has visto. Seguramente fuese de otro plugin. Según la oficial del plugin que estas usando https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#i18n, basta con usar `$.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');`

```js
$(function(){
  $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "d-m-Y"
  });
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text"
         id="idFechaAltaConv"
         class="form-control input-sm datepicker " />
</div>
```

**NOTA:** En este caso estamos iniciando el plugin una vez se ha cargado la página haciendo uso de `$(function(){..})` para esperar la carga de Jquery. Pero podríamos poner esta funcionalidad en cualquier otra función y llamarla cuando lo necesitemos.

```
function aplicarDatetimepicker(selector, formato, codigoIdioma) {
    $(selector).datetimepicker({
        format: formato
    });
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale(codigoIdioma);
}
```