# Cambiar idioma en datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetimepicker

Tengo un datetimepicker pero sale predeterminado en ingles, quiero saber si hay manera de cambiarlo a español.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.datetimepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
      'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'
    ],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'
    ],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Mi&eacute;rcoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'S&aacute;bado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mi&eacute;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'S&aacute;b'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'S&aacute;'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
  };
  $.datetimepicker.setDefaults($.datetimepicker.regional['es']);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fecha").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-MM-D',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<input class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" placeholder="fecha -- " type="text" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sale este error en consola:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'regional' of
> undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes  especificar el idioma que quieres asi:

```js
$(function () {
        $("#fecha").datepicker({
            language: 'es'
        });
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<input class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" placeholder="fecha -- " type="text"/>
```

Tu CDN debe de apuntar a la version del idioma que quieres `locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js`

Comment: Hola, dice jQuery.Deferred exception: option language is not recognized!  en consola y ya no abre el calendario

Comment: has descargalo la carpeta locales de la libreria?

Comment: ya quedo listo, Gracias

Comment: La pregunta hace referencia a datetimepicker no datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de **datetimepicker** la forma que lo solucione fue con...

(Era un campo que se generaba de forma dinámica)

```
      $('.js-datetimepickerNotMinutes').datetimepicker.dates['en'] = {
                    days: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
                    daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab", "Dom"],
                    daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa", "Do"],
                    months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
                    monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                    today: "Hoy"
                };


  $('.js-datetimepickerNotMinutes').datetimepicker({
              uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                                defaultDate: "+1w",
                                showOn: 'button',
                                numberOfMonths: 1,
                                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:00',
                                language: 'es',
                                daysShort: ["Sunx", "Monx", "Tuex", "Wedx", "Thux", "Frix", "Satx", "Sunx"],
                                weekStart: 1,
                                minView: "day",
                                minuteStep: 61,
                                autoclose: true
                              });
```

Ya que en mi caso solamente con el ...

```
language: 'es',
```

No bastaba.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({
locale: 'es',
format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
daysOfWeekDisabled: [6],     
//defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
disabledDates: [
  // moment("12/25/2013"),      
  "11-11-2021",
  "11-10-2021",
  "11-05-2021"
], });



<div class="form-group">
  <label>Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="reservationdate" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#reservationdate" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd/mm/yyyy" data-mask/>
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#reservationdate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
     <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
     </div>
   </div>                                 
</div>
```

Agrega este ruta de moment: locale.js
[image: Agrega este ruta de moment: locale.js]

Resultado:

[image: Resultado del codigo]